# Output image in datagrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, .net-4.0

How can you do custom output for a bound gridview? I.e. I have a boolean field in a database, rather than write out True as I get from <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BoolField") %>, I'd like to put an image (such as a tick) in the grid view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Eval is Evil. There is a solution with eval but I will skip it on purpose.

There are 2 other solutions. You can use the ImageField and shape the data to pass the corret URL for the picture in a special property that you should specify in the DataImageUrlField property of the ImageField.

The other solution is to add a template field with an Image control and handle the RowDataBound event get the data for the row from the event arguments e.Row.DataItem cast it to the type of the items in your data source and extract the boolean value. Then you can use FindControl to get the Image control and assing its properties. Something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvTest.DataSource = new bool[] { true, false };
    gvTest.DataBind();
}

protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image imgBool = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("imgBool");
        bool data = (bool)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (data)
        {
            imgBool.ImageUrl = "/images/true.jpg";
            imgBool.AlternateText = "This is true";
        }
        else
        {
            imgBool.ImageUrl = "/images/false.jpg";
            imgBool.AlternateText = "This is false";
        }
    }
}
```

This might seem like a lot of work but remember that you can use this same handler to work with all the colums in your grid in a type safe way.

Comment: Thanks mate, exactly what I was after.

Comment: Can I ask though, why is Eval evil?

Comment: Eval is evil because it is string based. Imagine that you are binding the grid to a list of products and bind some column via Eval to the ProductName property. However later you decide to change the property name to Name. You will not get compile time error if you use eval. If you bind via the databind events you will. You may notice that FindControl also uses strings but FindControl is scoped in a single pair of files (the markup and the code behind files) and you are much more likely to see it and test the related code path if you change the name of the control.

Answer (score 0):

[Displaying Images in a GridView Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)

Comment: Did you read what I wrote or just Googled it? I am not trying to output an image URL.

Comment: The img html tag need src param. It specifies the URL of an image